# How to assign attribute to dropdown menu in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, drop-down-menu

I am using form helper to create a dropdown menu, I have looked at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html but it doesn't specify how to assign attributes to dropdown menu. I want to add `i`d and `class` to my dropdwon menu. How do I do that? Thanks for the help.

My code

```
$JNarray=array(
'company1'=>'company1,
'company2'=>'company2
);

echo form_label("company");
echo form_dropdown('company',$JNarray);
```

The above will create

```
<select name='company'>  //I want to add 'id' and class attribute to select
  <option value='company1'>company1</option>
  <option value='company2'>company2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the fourth argument:

```
<?php
echo form_dropdown('company', $JNarray, NULL, 'id="company" class="some-class"');
```

Comment: is there any way to add attribute to the certain "option"? I want to add 'disabled' attribute to some of opptions